# Ninject to Unity using register types getting single instance controller error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I had `Ninject` and had a tonne of mappings configured. I've started using `Unity` now, and I used the code below to create all mappings:

```
        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            /* Cant remember what I was using here */);
```

But now, when I run my MVC 5 project I'm getting this error:

> A single instance of controller cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seemed to do the trick:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.Transient);
```